# React Constants inside a Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants, export

I need help to export the constants. I am getting different errors when i try to search for this on google or other related topics at stackoverflow.

This is my Printer.jsx

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";


// export individual features (can export var, let,
// const, function, class)
export let ePosDev = new window.epson.ePOSDevice();
export const ePosDevice = useRef();
export const printer = useRef();

export function connectFunction() { 
  ePosDevice.current = ePosDev;
  ePosDev.connect("192.168.1.254", 8080, (data) => {
  if (data === "OK") {
    ePosDev.createDevice(
      "local_printer",
      ePosDev.DEVICE_TYPE_PRINTER,
      { crypto: true, buffer: false },
      (devobj, retcode) => {
        if (retcode === "OK") {
          printer.current = devobj;
        } else {
          throw retcode;
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    throw data;
  }
}); };
```

I need to add the const connect to the App.js so that if the App is starting the connection is also starting. The second is that i need to add the const print to ReactB.js-file so if content of ReactB.js-page is loading the print-request should be send.

Thanks for your help! Stuck at this since 5 hours and dont know how to deal with this problems.

Comment: What do you want to export?

Comment: @EdwinDijasChiwona I want to export the const connect and the const print. I dont know how to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason you are exporting Printer() as default? I'm not sure the exact problem you're trying to solve, but you could drop the Printer() function entirely, and export the connect() and print() functions directly. Then in your app.js, you would just import { connect } from './printer.js' and use connect() wherever it is needed.

Comment: @roadrunner343 Can you help me to do this? I tried this way but getting this error: "Invalid hook call"

Comment: Does it need to be a .JSX component? I'm not seeing anything in Printer.jsx that returns JSX. It looks to me like it should just be a standard .js utils file. In which case you could just define two different functions (One for connect and one for print) and export them, much the same as you do Printer() now. If you want to export the constant though, you'll just need to export them AFTER they are defined with export { constName };

Comment: @roadrunner343 I am beginner. If there are no jsx components it could also a js file. Can you help me to create this code for the js file with the two different functions? If i create two different functions, i am getting this error: printer.current is not defined when i try to print.

Comment: Honestly, I think you need ditch React for a couple hours,and just play around with vanilla Javascript imports, exports, and functions. You're getting the error because you're attempting to use the userRef() React hook. When you created two different functions, printer.current is undefined because the react hook was no longer populating it. I would spend some time reviewing the MDN page on export as well as passing arguments between functions. Learning React without learning JS fundamentals is going to be very difficult.

Comment: @roadrunner343 I know, and it is very interesting to learn but for today I want to get this to run. Can you please help me? It is not too much code.

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not going to write the code for you. I've already highlighted several things that don't make sense to me and without seeing the full code base, I can't tell you exactly how it should or should not be written. Regardless of how much you want to get it to run today, you first need to learn how imports/exports work in general, and how you can pass a value into another function so that it has access to whatever value printer.current holds. Once you learn those two things, you should be able to implement the first on your own. And there's time to learn both of those concepts today :)

Comment: @roadrunner343 I try to create the functions and also I imported them. But can you help me with a small thing? You wrote:  "you'll just need to export them AFTER they are defined with export". I dont unterstand how to export the constants! This is what i code: export const ePosDevice = useRef();. Then I am getting this:  React Hook "useRef" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function. Can you help me to solve only this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your main issue stems around how to export constants. I recommend checking out MDN for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Below is an excerpt on named exports that is relevant to your scenario.

```
// export features declared earlier
export { myFunction, myVariable };

// export individual features (can export var, let,
// const, function, class)
export let myVariable = Math.sqrt(2);
export function myFunction() { ... };
```

So for your example, it would just be a matter of adding declaring the const with `export const connect = value;` or adding `export { connect };` after it is declared.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not help me to solve this problem: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: When I starting with this: export const ePosDevice = useRef(); export const printer = useRef(); and then the export function connectFunction() {  } I am getting this error

Comment: I updated my Code, please have a quick look...# @roadrunner

Comment: You need to revaluate what you are trying to do and why - like I stated in the comments to your original post, from what I can see right now, I see no reason for Printer to be a React component, and you can only use reactHooks in a react component. Get rid of the useRef() hooks and store whatever value you need in a variable. Like I mentioned previously, it's going to be immensely beneficial for you to step away from React and learn JS fundamentals first.